# Reading png does not give expected result

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import misc

img = misc.imread('W0002_0001.png')
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

I want to read the first image that can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/sshaqehk80lsalt/AABpgwr8rlewi-KUkcpq2Rn6a?dl=0). The problem is that the image displayed is not the one I should see. I get:

[image]

When I should be getting:

[image]

When looking in detail, I noticed that the real image could be seen in the first row of the obtained image, repeated several times.

Also, I had several segfaults when trying to import the image several times in a row with IPython, although it seems like I cannot always reproduce the issue.

I tried reading the image with Pillow and it worked fine.

Do you have any idea what might cause that?

Comment: I saved the image (md5 sum is `0d5e84238299eb996a0f58716354a7e6`), loaded it with `scipy.misc.imread`, and displayed it with `imshow(img)`, and I got the image that you say you should be getting.  (Mac OS X, python 2.7.10, numpy 1.9.2, scipy 0.16.0, matplotlib 1.4.3)

Comment: I keep getting the same result : Mac OS X, Python 3.4.2, numpy 1.9.2, scipy 0.16.0, matplotlib 1.4.3

Comment: I tried it again with Python 3.4.3 (other package versions the same), and it still works.  So unfortunately, all I can say is "works for me".  If you are sometimes getting segfaults, then possibly something in your installation of the python packages is corrupted.

Comment: I use pyenv to manage my python versions, could it come from there ?

Comment: I don't know; I haven't used pyenv.

Comment: Do you use Pillow (mine is 2.9.0) ? With the fourth image, I always get a segfault.

Comment: `PIL.PILLOW_VERSION` is `2.7.0`.

Comment: OK, I updated PIL so `PIL.PILLOW_VERSION` is 2.9.0, and I also get a segfault with the fourth image.  So it's not just you. :)

Comment: Damn.. I downgraded to pillow 2.7.0 but still get a segfault for the fourth image. How could I check the integrity of an image ? It might come from there.

Comment: I checked the file with pngcheck (http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/apps/pngcheck.html), and it didn't report any errors.

Comment: I checked also and no problem. Do you think it comes from the Pillow library or from scipy ? I have started looking at the sources but cannot see any problem so far..

Comment: Possibly scipy.  I'll create on issue on the scipy github repo.

Comment: Scipy issue: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/5285.  Please add any additional information there.

Comment: It's Pillow/PIL bug: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/350

Comment: Waiting for the result, how can I transform my png image to an array. I have an assignment coming and cannot wait..